# edit/save a file within shell script

Tags: bash, shell, vim, pipe

I think this question fall under pipes, am bad at it.

Using one of my shell script, a file is generated with millions of rows.
Before I can use it with another command, I need to edit this file. I need to add a text e.g 'txt' in front of every line.

What i am currently doing now is, 
-exit the shell script after file is generated
-open it in vim
-use command :g/^/s//txt/g to add txt at start of each line
-save file
-use it in remaining shell script

I am sure there would be a more efficient way, which i am not aware of. thanks for the help.

Comment: Use `sed 's/^/txt/'`. See `man sed`.

Comment: do `sed 's/^/txt/g'`

Comment: @qqibrow The `g` flag is meaningless for an anchored pattern like that. It can only match once per-line.

Comment: I think you are getting lucky (sort of) that that vim command is doing what you want. The `//` part of that `s///` command is re-using the last search pattern (which happens to be `^` from the `/^/` pattern used with `:g`. Just in case you didn't realize what was happening there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As some people said in the comments, you can use GNU `sed` to do that:

```
sed -i 's/^/txt/' yourfile.txt
```

The `-i` stands for `--in-place` and edit your file instead of printing to *stdout*.

Comment: Note that `-i`  is a GNUism, or BSDism. It's not POSIX.